# Optimizing Sub-queries in SQL join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, query-optimization

I'm struggling to optimize a query which currently uses multiple subqueries. The subqueries run fast individually, but when joined together, are very slow. Below I've outlined a sample set of data and my current query.

**Purpose of Query**

To display the date different events occurred on an order

**Structure of data**

There is an Orders table and an Order History table

Orders

| Order | Part | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Planned |
| 2 | B | Released |
| 3 | A | Closed |
| 4 | B | Released |
| 5 | C | Closed |

Order History

| Timestamp | Order | Message | NewStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00am | 1 | Created | Planned |
| 10:15am | 2 | Created | Planned |
| 10:16am | 2 | Status Changed | Released |
| 10:20am | 3 | Created | Planned |
| 10:24am | 3 | Status Changed | Released |
| 10:25am | 2 | Status Changed | Planned |
| 10:30am | 4 | Created | Planned |
| 10:35am | 3 | Status Changed | Closed |
| 10:40am | 5 | Created | Planned |
| 10:45am | 4 | Status Changed | Released |
| 10:50am | 5 | Status Changed | Released |
| 10:55am | 2 | Status Changed | Released |
| 11:00am | 5 | Status Changed | Planned |
| 11:05am | 5 | Status Changed | Released |
| 11:15am | 5 | Status Changed | Closed |
| 11:20am | 3 | Status Changed | Released |
| 11:25am | 3 | Status Changed | Closed |

**Desired Result**

| Order | Part | Status | Created Date | First Release | Latest Release | Closed Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Planned | 10:00am |  |  |  |
| 2 | B | Released | 10:15am | 10:16am | 10:55am |  |
| 3 | A | Closed | 10:20am | 10:24am | 11:20am | 11:25am |
| 4 | B | Released | 10:30am | 10:45am | 10:45am |  |
| 5 | C | Closed | 10:40am | 10:50am | 11:05am | 11:15am |

**Current Query**

My current query does a subquery against the history table for each timestamp field (Created, First Release, Latest Release, Closed) and then joins them all up:

```
SELECT 
c.order
,c.part
,c.status
,c.cDate
,fr.frDate
,lr.lrDate
,cd.cdDate
FROM
(SELECT 
 o.order
 ,o.part
 ,o.status
 ,min(oh.timestamp)
 FROM order o
 JOIN order_history oh
 ON o.order = oh.order
 WHERE oh.message = 'Created' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Planned'
 group by o.order, o.part, o.status) c
JOIN 
(SELECT 
 o.order
 ,o.part
 ,o.status
 ,min(oh.timestamp)
 FROM order o
 JOIN order_history oh
 ON o.order = oh.order
 WHERE oh.message = 'Status Changed' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Released'
 group by o.order, o.part, o.status) fr
ON c.order = fr.order and c.part = fr.part and c.status = fr.status
JOIN 
(SELECT 
 o.order
 ,o.part
 ,o.status
 ,max(oh.timestamp)
 FROM order o
 JOIN order_history oh
 ON o.order = oh.order
 WHERE oh.message = 'Status Changed' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Released'
 group by o.order, o.part, o.status) lr
ON c.order = lr.order and c.part = lr.part and c.status = lr.status
JOIN 
(SELECT 
 o.order
 ,o.part
 ,o.status
 ,max(oh.timestamp)
 FROM order o
 JOIN order_history oh
 ON o.order = oh.order
 WHERE oh.message = 'Status Changed' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Closed'
 group by o.order, o.part, o.status) cd
ON c.order = cd.order and c.part = cd.part and c.status = cd.status
```

So as you can see... it's ugly! And really slow. What can I do to optimize?

Please keep in mind this is much simplified, fake example. I've tried to show the complexity in the data and query. Apologies if there are mistakes in the query, but I can verify that the current query does work to give me the results I want, so I'm not looking for just corrections, but optimizations.

Comment: "Please keep in mind this is much simplified, fake example. " - which is therefore pretty much useless.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[mre] [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)

Comment: There is a bug in the preview formatter, it formats a table as if you had put in the obligatory blank line before it whereas the published version fails to format. This is a faq at [meta] and/or [meta.se]. But question post tables should have minimal representative/appropriate data. Also: Debug questions require a [mre]. So such tables should be given instead as initialization code (in columns) as part of a [mre].  [ask] [Help]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I spent a long time googling and building the above examples. They may not meet your standards, but I tried. Prior times I provide example data, I got only Reponses responding to the data quality, which isn't helpful. Doing this at least got me a real answer, and it's been very helpful! Sorry this didn't meet standards but, hopefully you didn't waste your time.

Comment: @JonHeller - While it is possible that this question may be a duplicate of something, the one you linked to was not a duplicate of this question. That question has multiple nested sub-queries and the performance was improved by preventing query rewriting and stopping the predicates from being pushed to the outer query; this one has all the sub-queries on the same level and can be solved using aggregation - it cannot be solved by adding `ROWNUM` to the sub-queries.

Comment: Typically if you don't give actual code including DDL & data (possibly generated by code to be big) forming a [mre] a Q&A just can't help debug or optimize. In particular for optimization behaviour is chaotically dependent on details. However there are Q&A re general principles & techniques of optimization. Though this post shows no research effort into them or other aspects of trying to answer this question. The site is a repository of good & searchable/findable Q&A, not all questions are on-topic. [tour] See the help & sites I've linked to.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: @MTO It's difficult to see, but I think the questions are very related. This question only has a generic, fake query, and I think the heart of the question is "The subqueries run fast individually, but when joined together, are very slow." The question I used for the [duplicate close](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39741901/409172) similarly boils down to "Prior to joining, I have tested both individual queries and they turned out fine. Only 1-2 secs and I get the result. But joining the two, I end up with 3 hrs of waiting." And in both of those cases, `ROWNUM` works.

Comment: @MTO Either way, your answer looks good, and I don't want to start an edit war over this if you or the OP find it useful. Thanks for explaining your edit and vote.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to optimize a query without access to the real query, table and index structures, and execution plan. However simplifying it to remove the subqueries and reduce the number of joins is unlikely to hurt, and might give you a better place to start investigating the plan and look for real optimization opportunities.

It also doesn't help that your 'simplified, fake' version uses illegal identifiers and has various other errors (including needing outer joins to get all five rows back), which you said to ignore but as Mitch commented, those things and the general fakeness make it kind of useless. Still, as a general idea of where to start, perhaps, with your example you could rewrite it using conditional aggregation, for example as:

```
SELECT 
o.order_num
,o.part
,o.status
,MIN(CASE WHEN oh.message = 'Created' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Planned' THEN oh.timestamp END) AS cDate
,MIN(CASE WHEN oh.message = 'Status Changed' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Released' THEN oh.timestamp END) AS frDate
,MAX(CASE WHEN oh.message = 'Status Changed' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Released' THEN oh.timestamp END) AS lrDate
,MAX(CASE WHEN oh.message = 'Status Changed' AND oh.NewStatus = 'Closed' THEN oh.timestamp END) AS cdDate
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_history oh
ON o.order_num = oh.order_num
GROUP BY o.order_num, o.part, o.status
ORDER BY o.order_num, o.part, o.status
```

| ORDER_NUM | PART | STATUS | CDATE | FRDATE | LRDATE | CDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Planned | 10:00am | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | B | Released | 10:15am | 10:16am | 10:55am | *null* |
| 3 | A | Close | 10:20am | 10:24am | 11:20am | 11:25am |
| 4 | B | Released | 10:30am | 10:45am | 10:45am | *null* |
| 5 | C | Closed | 10:40am | 10:50am | 11:05am | 11:15am |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vIMqppjg) including a working version of your query with legal identifiers (though 'timestamp' still isn't ideal) and other changes, and this modified query.

(This works with the 'timestamp' as strings with your fake values, but would also work with real dates or timestamps, or course. And it doesn't necessarily need to be an outer join if there is always a 'Created' record, which seems likely.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT m.order_num,
       o.part,
       m.status,
       m.cdate,
       m.frdate,
       m.lrdate,
       m.cddate
FROM   order_history
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY order_num
         ORDER BY timestamp
         MEASURES
           LAST(newstatus)           AS status,
           FIRST(timestamp)          AS cdate,
           FIRST(released.timestamp) AS frdate,
           LAST(released.timestamp)  AS lrdate,
           LAST(closed.timestamp)    AS cddate
         PATTERN (created (planned|released|closed)*)
         DEFINE
           created  AS message = 'Created',
           planned  AS message = 'Status Changed' AND newstatus = 'Planned',
           released AS message = 'Status Changed' AND newstatus = 'Released',
           closed   AS message = 'Status Changed' AND newstatus = 'Closed'
       ) m
       INNER JOIN orders o
       ON o.order_num = m.order_num
```

*Note: The only thing the `orders` table is necessary for is the `part` column and everything else can be generated from the `order_history` table; so if you don't need that column then you can eliminate the join.*

Which, [borrowing Alex Poole's sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78124955/1509264), outputs:

| ORDER_NUM | PART | STATUS | CDATE | FRDATE | LRDATE | CDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Planned | 10:00am | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | B | Released | 10:15am | 10:16am | 10:55am | *null* |
| 3 | A | Closed | 10:20am | 10:24am | 11:20am | 11:25am |
| 4 | B | Released | 10:30am | 10:45am | 10:45am | *null* |
| 5 | C | Closed | 10:40am | 10:50am | 11:05am | 11:15am |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A-7Qrfq1)